# Move line include indent

Tags: vimrc

How do you move a single line in Vim with a shortcut, and make the indent always be correct, as is displayed here:
https://twitter.com/manucorporat/status/885054730812223489?s=09

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it meet your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy peasy. To map <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd> and <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> you can do the following:

To make it go **down**:

```
:nmap <C-DOWN> ddp==
```

To make it go **up**:

```
:nmap <C-UP> ddkP==
```

You can choose other keys to map, and you can just type the commands and repeat, no need to map. Very basic stuff.

---

Edited: as the answer by Naumann bellow pointed out, vim already have

- `]p` : `p==`
- `[p` : `P==` (upper-case P)

So, if you still want to map the keys, you may use that instead of `p==` or `P==`

---

BTW, I made a video as well.

https://youtu.be/BARhbRzOa1Y

Edited:
An explanation to this issue can be read [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_lines_up_or_down)

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15399297/670521) of how map <kbd>ALT</kbd> key also uses exactly this example to illustrate it.

Comment: doesnt work. so what do i put in the vimrc file?

Comment: _doesnt work_ doesn't tell much, does it? What is the error message? In the `vimrc` you don't need the colon. Just `nmap <C-UP> ddkP==`. Analogous to go down. Try first directly in the vim command line and test. It works here just fine.

Comment: it works. (: i do noremap though.

Comment: Good that it works for you. ;) Suggestion: you may try `nnoremap` instead of `noremap`. Keep your `insertion mode` clean. But whatever works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

Vim already has `]p` and `[p` for this

- `]p` : like `p`, but adjust indent to current line
- `[p` : adjust indent to current line

Read [`:help ]p`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%5dp) and [`:help [p`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%5bp) for more information.

Comment: Is this pure vim or the plugin `unimpaired`?

Comment: It is pure vim. Try    :help ]p

Comment: so how does one go about acquiring the functionality requested? i tried putting that in the vimrc, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
nnoremap <A-j> :m .+1<CR>==
nnoremap <A-k> :m .-2<CR>==
inoremap <A-j> <Esc>:m .+1<CR>==gi
inoremap <A-k> <Esc>:m .-2<CR>==gi
vnoremap <A-j> :m '>+1<CR>gv=gv
vnoremap <A-k> :m '<-2<CR>gv=gv
```

EDIT:
Thank dr-beco Indeed you need the following configuration in your vimrc file in order to have your alt key mapped.

```
"Make Alt key work
let c='a'
while c <= 'z'
  exec "set <A-".c.">=\e".c
  exec "imap \e".c." <A-".c.">"
  let c = nr2char(1+char2nr(c))
endw
```

Then you can use it with alt-j / alt-k

Comment: Given the [credits](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_lines_up_or_down). Also, mapping `ALT` works better using `<M-j>` instead of `<A-j>`. It is not clear why, but I've experience with this problem in two systems (linux/mac).